# Conceptualizing Contraction over $C([a,b])$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, contraction-operator

Let $h\in C([a,b]), \delta\in C([a,b]\times[a,b])$ and $$L_k := \sup_{x\in[a,b]}\int_a^b|\delta(x,y)|dy < 1$$
Show that $T$ defines a contraction with konstant $L_k$ where 
$$T:C([a,b])\rightarrow C([a,b]),\quad f\mapsto h + \int_a^b \delta(\cdot, y)f(y)dy$$
I am finding it hard to conceptualize the problem, as the only examples of contractions I have seen are $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. How can one start a proof for this problem?

Comment: As always, start with the definition.  I'm also not seeing why $L_k<1$, is this assumed or does it follow from the conditions?

Comment: @MichaelBurr it is given in the definition of $L_k$ so I believe it is a condition for $\delta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are taking the sup norm on $C[a,b]$. For any $f,g \in C[a,b]$ we have $Tf(x)-Tg(x)=\int_a^{b} \delta (x,y)[f(y)-g(y)]dy$ so $|Tf(x)-Tg(x)| \leq L_k \sup \{|f(y)-g(y)|: a \leq y \leq b\}$. Since this is true for all $x$ we get $\|Tf-Tg\| \leq L_k\|f-g\|$. Since $L_k <1$ it follows that $T$ is a contraction.

Comment: Thank you, sir, however, I fail to understand how we can make the jump from the first equation to the second when inside the integral is a product of two functions of y.

Comment: @RubenKruepper Just pull out the supremum of $|f(y)-g(y)|$ from the integral.